# Converting IplImage into 1D vector in OpenCV

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I want to convert a mXn IplImage into a  (m*n) x 1 1D vector. Can this be done with any function in OpenCV?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`cvReshape`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvreshape#cvReshape)

> ```
> CvMat* cvReshape(const CvArr* arr, CvMat* header, int newCn, 
> int newRows=0)
> ```
>
> #### Changes shape of matrix/image without copying data.
>
> And the next example converts a 3x3
>   matrix to a single 1x9 vector:
>
> ```
> CvMat* mat = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_32F);
> CvMat row_header, *row;
> row = cvReshape(mat, &row_header, 0, 1);
> ```

Comment: thanks for help...so CV_32FC3 works for rgb color image?..then its 1X27 vector?

Comment: Check out the example in the link I sent. There, they convert a 320x240x3 image into a  960x240x1 image.